# mongodb array aggregation extract to parent

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregate, aggregation

I am trying to get first date from inner array in mongodb object and add it to it's parent with aggregation. Example:

```
car: {
  "model": "Astra",
  "productions": [
    "modelOne": {
      "dateOfCreation": "2019-09-30T10:15:25.026+00:00",
      "dateOfEstimation": "2017-09-30T10:15:25.026+00:00",
      "someOnterInfo": "whatever"
    },
    "modelTwo": {
      "dateOfCreation": "2017-09-30T10:15:25.026+00:00",
      "dateOfEstimation": "2019-09-30T10:15:25.026+00:00",
      "someOnterInfo": "whatever"
    }
  ]
}
```

to be turned in

```
car: {
  "model": "Astra",
  "earliestDateOfEstimation": "2017-09-30T10:15:25.026+00:00",
  "earliestDateOfCreation": "2017-09-30T10:15:25.026+00:00"
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `modelOne` and `modelTwo` are unknown when you start your aggregation. The key step is to run [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) along with [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) in order to get rid of those two values. Then you can just use [$min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/index.html) to get "earliest" values:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            dates: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$car.productions",
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: { model: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $objectToArray: "$$this" }, 0 ] } },
                            in: "$$model.v"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            "car.model": 1,
            "car.earliestDateOfEstimation": { $min: "$dates.dateOfEstimation" },
            "car.earliestDateOfCreation": { $min: "$dates.dateOfCreation" },
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IPL_qWNzT7U)

EDIT:

First step can be simplified if there's always `modelOne`, 'modelTwo'... (fixed number)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            dates: { $concatArrays: [ "$car.productions.modelOne", "$car.productions.modelTwo" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            "car.model": 1,
            "car.earliestDateOfEstimation": { $min: "$dates.dateOfEstimation" },
            "car.earliestDateOfCreation": { $min: "$dates.dateOfCreation" },
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground (2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-t-NgyWX98T)

Comment: Nope, they are not unknown

Comment: @IntoTheDeep okay, so it becomes a bit easier

Comment: What about array has 500 items?

Comment: Hi, problem is that I have multiple cars. So, when I add input: "$productions", it doesn't work

Comment: So can you edit your post and show your real data and how the value should be calculated ?

Comment: @IntoTheDeep try this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zLD7IKpYz6o or https://mongoplayground.net/p/8PLZTNIkGU- depending on your requirements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206239/discussion-between-intothedeep-and-mickl).